# CSS search box how to keep it responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I need little help to make my search box responsive

HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div id='search-box'>
        <form action='/search' id='search-form' method='get' target='_top'>
            <input class='search-text' name='q' placeholder='Search by name' type='text'/>
            <button id='search-button' type='submit'>src</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search-box {
    width:100%;
    height:44px;
    background:#ffd965;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    display:block;
}

#search-form {
    positoin:absolute;
    left:16px;
    right:16px;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#search-text {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    background:  transparent;       
}

#search-box input[type="text"] {

}

#search-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    height: 42px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: transparent ;
    background-image:url('../images/search.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and my code is : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi_idevtechnolabs/La9r6)

Comment: Use MediaQueries.Are you developer?Designer?

Comment: You should elaborate on the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: I try to Upload Image but is says you need at least 10 like to upload image.: @Shannon

Comment: also I need it as we can see searchbox in mobile , yes this will going to be search box for mobile app. @Shannon

Comment: But first need to fix for full width: when we make it 100% it go out of form div.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.search-text {
    width:50%;
}
```

see this

http://jsfiddle.net/La9r6/2/

Comment: Jay, that will display the search box half its size after it responds. If she uses class="span6" that is already set for 50%. But the search box must remain 100% inside the 50% div

Comment: you can now modify in above width to 100% or any size that you want to set.

see this http://jsfiddle.net/La9r6/3/

Comment: BUt I need it 100% just like search box in mobiles . and 10px margin from both size (left and right)

Comment: when we do 100% it go out of main box and it looks ugly :( @JayDeepNimavat ,

Comment: @LOTUSMS when we do 100% it go out of main box and it looks ugly :(

Comment: for responsiveness you can add this, if you looking for other style like margin or else you have to add style for it or for mobile view you have to write media query.

Comment: go for 90% or 95% or else and see which is looking great and set it.

Comment: remove position absolute from #search-form css.

Comment: @JayDeepNimavat All Good suggestions

Comment: If you gating right answer of satisfaction than right my answer or vote up.